# Getting Docker Right - Visual Studio 2017 and Windows 10 Home

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

According to the [instructions available in response to an earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48515185/681009) about this same configuration (VS2017 on Win10/Home) it should be *possible* to get this to all run correctly. However when the instructions provided tell me to

> 6. Open windows power shell in administrator mode and type ‘docker-machine ls’ to confirm that default vm is running. Can also do
>      ‘docker-machine status default’ and it should return ‘running’

in the powershell (adm) I see a state of Timeout (or a 'status' of Stopped) 
[image]
Since this doesn't match the instructions provided I cannot progress.

At present I have the boilerplate Visual Studio 2017 AspNet Core with Docker Support (plus not anything) which, when I build, returns with

> "Visual Studio Container Tools requires Docker to be running before
>   building, debugging or running a containerized project"

searching on that brought me to the linked question above, where the first answer has me launching the VS solution from the Docker Quickstart as

> /c/Program\ Files\ (x86)/Microsoft\ Visual\ Studio/2017/Professional/Common7/IDE/devenv.exe C:\_dev\xxy\xxy.sln

Which gets me to the point where I have a successful build but the output [debug] asks:

> ------------------------------------------------------------------- You may only use the Microsoft .NET Core Debugger (vsdbg) with Visual
>   Studio Code, Visual Studio or Visual Studio for Mac software to help
>   you develop and test your applications.
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------- **Did you mean to run dotnet SDK commands?** Please install dotnet SDK
>   from: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=798306&clcid=0x409 The
>   target process exited without raising a CoreCLR started event. Ensure
>   that the target process is configured to use .NET Core. This may be
>   expected if the target process did not run on .NET Core. The program
>   '[31] dotnet' has exited with code 145 (0x91). The program '' has
>   exited with code 145 (0x91).

*(NOTE: The dotnet SDK is installed)*

I go to Package Manager Console in VS 2017 and check from here where I am informed that the default status is "Running"
[image]

My first thought is that I have more than one instance of Docker installed and the Powershell instance is not looking at the same one the Quickstart and PMC are monitoring.

Is this a plausible explanation and (if so) how might I resolve the matter? or (if not) where is the path forward from here.

Is there a something like "Docker Where" (where is docker 'running'?)