# Docker toolbox with Visual studio - Volume sharing is not enabled

Tags: visual-studio, docker, .net-core, virtualbox, docker-toolbox

I'm trying to get running a docker support with Visual studio 2017 for a .net core 2.0 web app running on linux containers. I'm working on machine with win 7 OS, so I must use a Docker toolbox with Virtual box. I've already checked this question: [How to get docker toolbox to work with .net core 2.0 project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45869766/how-to-get-docker-toolbox-to-work-with-net-core-2-0-project), but I got stuck in the following problem, when trying to run it with VS:

> Volume sharing is not enabled. Enable volume sharing in the docker ce
>   for windows settings

So far I know that there is a default volume mounted under the C:\Users, so my project files should be copied somewhere under this folder in case I don't want to mount any other volume. So I copied them there.

When I check the settings of my Virtual box, folder seems to be shared:

[image: Virtual box settings.]

I can even cd into this folder with command line, but still can't get over this problem. Any ideas about this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally I got this running. Error message comming from VS is very misleading and it has nothing to do with volume sharing. Eventually I realized that problem is in running a debugger, because when I ran solution with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> everything was ok and container started correctly. Problem occurred only when running with <kbd>F5</kbd> and trying to attach a debugger.

Then I found some clues in console output. VS tries to download some tooling for debugging containers with powershell script named `GetVsDbg.ps1`. When running this script I could observe errors like:

> Add-Type : Cannot add type. The assembly
> 'System.IO.Compression.FileSystem' could not be found.

Finally I fixed this issue by updating powershell version which was somehow in collision with my .net framework installed on my machine.

Comment: Interesting...I think I had that issue in the past too. Not sure how but it resolved itself probably when I updated my visual studio IDE. You could perhaps change your question title to that error message which is more likely a search term in google. FYI - you can store your source code in c:\Users\{username}\source\repos. I think thats where new vs tries to store by default these days.

Comment: When i try to install from that link, i get a certificate error -_-

Answer (score 2):

Well in my case it turned out that I had **changed my windows password** and docker wasn't able to get access. 
So it was just

1. uncheck shared drives
2. Apply
3. Check again. Enter **new** password
4. restart docker

Answer (score 1):

Below setting helped me getting rid of this error. Check the drive you want to share and click apply. This might ask you your network credential just enter in case it pops up.

[Docker settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YdwOU.png)

Thanks,
Rakesh

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by running following command in Powershell:

```
docker network create nat
```

Answer (score 0):

I got same issue attempting to publish an Azure Function App to a Container Registry.
Newer version of **Docker Desktop for Windows** 2.3, has new interface. I had to got to Resources|File Sharing and add a new Folder. This resolved that issue...