# Is it possible to use Docker without Windows 10 pro?

Tags: windows, docker, docker-toolbox

I need to install Docker on my pc with Windows 10 home. I read that I can only install Docker Toolbox. Is there any way to have the latest Docker version instead without upgrading my pc to windows 10 pro?

Thanks

Comment: Whats wrong with docker toolbox?

Comment: There's less documentation, I'm trying to run a asp.net core app with docker but I'm not finding good documentation to do it with toolbox

Comment: It's also failing on visual studio, i'm following this post and getting the same error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45869766/how-to-get-docker-toolbox-to-work-with-net-core-2-0-project?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Update**

Docker can now be installed on Windows 10 Home (version 2004 or higher).
Refer to this article for installation instructions

https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install-windows-home/

**Old Answer**

Docker for Windows requires Hyper-V, and Hyper-V requires Windows 10 Pro (or Windows Server). So no, you can't run Docker without upgrading.

https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install/

> - **README FIRST for Docker Toolbox and Docker Machine users:** Docker for Windows requires Microsoft Hyper-V to run. The Docker for Windows installer enables Hyper-V for you, if needed, and restart your machine.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/quick-start/enable-hyper-v

> #### Check Requirements

> - Windows 10 Enterprise, Professional, or Education

- 64-bit Processor with Second Level Address Translation (SLAT).
- CPU support for VM Monitor Mode Extension (VT-c on Intel CPU's).
- Minimum of 4 GB memory.

> The Hyper-V role **cannot** be installed on Windows 10 Home.

Comment: If it uses WSL2 exclusively does that mean that on Win10 Home Docker Desktop only supports using Linux containers and not Windows Server containers? If so that's a significant limitation that it would be nice to see documented somewhere.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure Windows needs Linux to run Windows on Windows -.-

Answer (score 5):

You can now install Docker Desktop on Windows Home machines using the WSL 2 backend. Docker Desktop on Windows Home is a full version of Docker Desktop for Linux container development.

https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install-windows-home/

Install Windows 10, version 2004 or higher.
Enable the WSL 2 feature on Windows. For detailed instructions, refer to the Microsoft documentation.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10

The following hardware prerequisites are required to successfully run WSL 2 on Windows 10 Home:

64 bit processor with Second Level Address Translation (SLAT)

4GB system RAM

BIOS-level hardware virtualization support must be enabled in the BIOS settings. For more information, see Virtualization.
https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/troubleshoot/#virtualization-must-be-enabled

Download and install the Linux kernel update package.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl2-kernel